# Websphere MQ clustering

Tags: cluster-computing, ibm-mq

I'm pretty new to websphere MQ, so please pardon me if I am not using the right terms. We are doing a project in which we need to setup a MQ cluster for high availability.

The client application maintains a pool of connection with the Queue Manager for subscribers and publishers. Suppose we have two Queue Managers in a cluster hosting the queues with the same names.  Each of the queue has its own set of subscribers and publishers which are cached by the client application. Suppose one of the queue manager goes down, the subscribers and publishers of the queues on that queue manager will die making the objects on client application defunct.

In this case can the following scenarios taken care of?

1] When first QueueManager crashes, the messages on its queues are transferred to other queuemanager in the cluster

2] When QueueManager comes up again, is there any mechanism to restore the publishers and subscribers. Currently we have written an automated recovery thread in the client application which tries to reconnect the failed publishers and subscriber. But in case of cluster setup, we fear that the publishers and subscribers will reconnect to the other running qmanager. And when the crashed queuemanager is restored, there will be no publishers and subscribers to it.

Can anybody please explain how to take care of above two scenarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to Shashi's answer, to get the most out of WMQ clustering you need to have a network hop between senders and receivers of messages.  WMQ clustering is about how QMgrs talk among themselves.  It has nothing to do with how client apps talk to QMgrs and does not replicate messages.  In a cluster when a message has to get from one QMgr to another, the cluster figures out where to route it.  If there are multiple clustered instances of a single destination queue, the message is eligible to be routed to any of them.  If there is no network hop between senders and receivers, then messages don't need to leave the local QMgr and therefore WMQ clustering behavior is never invoked, even though the QMgrs involved may participate in the cluster.

In a conventional WMQ cluster architecture, the receivers all listen on multiple instances of the same queue, with the same name, spread across multiple QMgrs.  The senders have one or more QMgrs where they can connect and send requests (fire-and-forget), possibly awaiting replies (request-reply).  Since the receivers of the messages provide some service, I call their QMgrs "Service Provider QMgrs."  The QMgrs where the senders of messages live are "Service Consumer" QMgrs because these apps are consumers of services.

The slide below is from a presentation I use on WMQ Architecture consulting engagements.

[image: An SOA architecture for WebSphere MQ]

Note that consumers of services - the things sending request messages - fail over.  Things listening on service endpoint queues and providing services do NOT fail over.  This is because of the need to make sure every active service endpoint queue is always served.  Typically each app instance holds an input handle on two or more queue instances.  This way a QMgr can go down and all app instances remain active.  If an app instance goes down, some other app instance continues to serve its queues.  This affinity of service providers to specific QMgrs also enables XA transactionality if needed.

The best way I've found to explain WMQ HA is a slide from the IMPACT conference:

[image: WebSphere MQ High Availability Options]

A WebSphere MQ cluster ensures that a service remains available, even though an instance of a clustered queue may be unavailable.  New messages in the cluster will route to the remaining queue instances.  A hardware cluster or multi-instance QMgr (MIQM) provides access to existing messages.  When one side of the active/passive pair goes down, there is a brief outage *on that QMgr only* while the failover occurs, then the secondary node takes over and makes any messages on the queues available again.  A network that combines both WMQ clusters and hardware clusters/MIQM provides the highest level of availability.

Keep in mind that in none of these configurations are messages replicated across nodes.  A WMQ message always has a single physical location.  For more on this aspect, please see [*Thoughts on Disaster Recovery*](https://t-rob.net/2012/10/24/thoughts-on-disaster-recovery/).

Answer (score 6):

WMQ Clustering is an advanced topic. You must first do a good amount of read up of WMQ and understand what clustering in WMQ world means before attempting anything.

WMQ Cluster differs in many ways from the traditional clusters. Unlike the traditional clusters, say in a Active/Passive cluster, data will be shared between active and passive instances of an application. At any point in time, the active instance of application will be processing data. When the active instance goes down, the passive instance takes over and starts processing. This is not the case in WMQ clusters where queue managers in a cluster are unique and hence queues/topics hosted by those queue managers are not shared. You might have the same queues/topics in both queue managers but since queue managers are different, messages, topics, subscriptions etc won't be shared.

Answering to your questions.
1) No. Messages,if persistent, will remain in the crashed queue manager. They will not be transferred to other queue manager. Since the queue manager itself is not available nothing can be done till the queue manager is brought up.
2)No. Queue manager can't do that. It's the duty of the application to check for queue manager availability and reconnect. WMQ provides automatic client reconnection feature where in the WMQ client libraries automatically reconnect to queue manager when they detect connection broken errors. This feature is available from WMQ v7.x and above with C and Java clients. C# client supports the feature from v7.1.

For your high availability requirement, you could look at using Multi instance queue manager feature of WMQ. This feature enables an Active/Passive instances of the same queue manager running on two different machines. Active instance of the queue manager will be handling client connections while the passive instance will be in sleep mode. Both instances will be sharing data and logs. Once the active instance goes down, the passive instance becomes active. You will have access to all the persistent messages that were in the queues before the active queue manager went down.

Read through the WMQ InfoCenter for more on Multi instance queue manager.